# EndlessScrollListener disapear first page

Tags: android

when i used EndlessScrollListener with recyclerView
it's worked but when load more data in page 2
the previous data disapear (page 1)

```
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new EndlessScrollListener(linearLayoutManager) {
        @Override
        public void onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount, RecyclerView view) {
            userpage++;
            GetAds(userpage);
        }


    });
```

and response eith retrofit

```
        APIRequests APIRequests = ApiClient.getClient().create(APIRequests.class);
    Call<JSONResponseGetAds> call = APIRequests.GetAds(userpage);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<JSONResponseGetAds>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<JSONResponseGetAds> call, Response<JSONResponseGetAds> response) {
            skeletonScreen.hide();
            data = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(response.body().getData()));
            adapter = new DataAdapterAds(getApplicationContext(),data);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<JSONResponseGetAds> call, Throwable t) {
            skeletonScreen.hide();
            Log.d("Error",t.getMessage());
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the adapter as global variable and pass the ArrayList as new data this way:

```
adapter = new DataAdapterAds(getApplicationContext(),data);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

APIRequests APIRequests = ApiClient.getClient().create(APIRequests.class);
Call<JSONResponseGetAds> call = APIRequests.GetAds(userpage);
call.enqueue(new Callback<JSONResponseGetAds>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<JSONResponseGetAds> call, Response<JSONResponseGetAds> response) {
        skeletonScreen.hide();
        data = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(response.body().getData()));
        adapter.addData(data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<JSONResponseGetAds> call, Throwable t) {
        skeletonScreen.hide();
        Log.d("Error",t.getMessage());
    }
});
```

And in your extended Adapter class use this logic:

```
public void addData(ArrayList<Data> data) {
    if (this.data == null) {
        this.data = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    if (data != null && !data.isEmpty()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < orders.length(); i++) {
            this.data.add(data);
        }
    }

    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```